# Final temperature after caustic dilution: Interpreting the graph

Tags: thermodynamics

I found the below graph in the Occidental Handbook on Caustic.

I'm confused, what may be the parameter noted on the four curves? 80-100-120-140 F?

The final Temperature is on the y-axis & initial water T is fixed as 70 F.

[image]

Comment: The labels on the curves are the initial  temperatures of the 50% caustic soda solutions.

Comment: @ChesterMiller I think you can post your comment as an answer:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The labels on the curves are the initial temperatures of the 50% caustic soda solutions.